# Get Click position in a view wrt center of view

Tags: android, android-layout

Like I have a FrameLayout. I want to get click position of a click with respect to center of that FrameLayout or the distance of that click from center of the view.
Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Location of your view on screen and its bounds:

```
int[] loc = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
int start_x = loc[0];
int start_y = loc[1];
int width = view.getWidth();
int height = view.getHeight();

view.addOnTouchListener(...)
```

The MotionEvent you get from the onTouch listener has the x and y location of the touch.

Thats all you need, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can setOnTouchListener whit the framelayout, like:

```
framelayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){//or MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, it's up to you
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

x and y are the coordinate, you can calculate the distance you need.